# wmi_exporter: How do I calculate the individual process cpu utilization in percentage?

Tags: wmi

software: wmi_exporter.
Can anyone tell me on how to calculate the single process cpu utilization in percentage? I think it may uses the matrices wmi_process_cpu_total{process="my process"} but I have no idea how to do it.

info about wmi_exporter
https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally solved it. It should use the formula sum(rate(wmi_process_cpu_total_time{process="my})）/ sum(wmi_cs_logical_processors)